# Failed to load launch URL with error: Error Domain=TVMLKitErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml

### Description:

I created a new TVML project and launched it. The first error was the App Transport Security, which I fixed via `Info.plist` :

```
App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads -> YES
```

Then I ran it again and I'm getting this error:

> Failed to load launch URL with error: (null)
>   appController(_:didFailWithError:) invoked with error: Error
>   Domain=TVMLKitErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"

The project seems to stop here (`application func` in `AppDelegate.swift`):

```
   appControllerContext.launchOptions["BASEURL"] = AppDelegate.tvBaseURL
   print(launchOptions) //returns nil
   //error on following line
   if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String: AnyObject] {
        //does not enter here
        for (kind, value) in launchOptions {
            appControllerContext.launchOptions[kind] = value
        }
    }
```

### What I've tried:

I attempted changing the tvBaseURL from "http://localhost:9001/" to `http://MY-IP-ADDRESS-HERE:9001/`

but that didn't change anything.

### Question:

What is causing this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't `as?` be `as!`?

Comment: check out my answer! If it helps - don't forget to mark it as solving answer

Comment: @moonvader I asked this question quite a while ago and I have not worked on it since. I thus do not know if your answer solves the problem, nor do I have any time to check. If you get more up votes in the future, I'll be sure to mark it as right. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You should start the server with port number

enter the following command in terminal

```
ruby -run -ehttpd . -p9001
```

And finally your **tvBaseURL** should navigate to the server folder like this

```
"http://yourLocalhost:9001/Downloads/TVMLCatalogUsingTVMLTemplates/Server/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem, I solved it by changing tvBaseURL in AppDelegate

```
static let tvBaseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:9001/Downloads/TVMLCatalogUsingTVMLTemplates/Server/"
```

As you see - I have to show exact path to Server folder. That also works if you put it to some web server.

Hope that it can help!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue. You need to pay close attention to the terminal output.

I got:

> ```
> [2019-03-15 12:28:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
> [2019-03-15 12:28:43] INFO  ruby 2.3.7 (2018-03-28) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:205:
> in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:9001 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
> ```

**Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:9001**

At this point you either have to choose a different port number (if you decide to do such then make sure your server's port and your Xcode's project port match) or kill the previous server by `ctrl + c` or just killing that terminal window.

Also note in some of Apple's sample projects the `ruby -run -ehttpd . -p9001` command is to be done in a folder named **Server** and for others it's just suppose to be done in the **App's main folder**. Just look into the README file to figure this out.